# Why did Kali incarnate as Duryodhana? For what reason was Duryodhana born earth for?

Tags: duryodhana

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

> The evil-minded and wicked king Duryodhana, the destroyer of the fair fame of the Kurus, was born of a portion of Kali on earth.

My question is, why was a portion of Kali born as Duryodhana in the first place? Why did Kali incarnate as Duryodhana? What was the reason for which, Duryodhana was born on earth?